# create and run multiproject gradle build

Tags: eclipse, gradle, dependencies

Following question:
My goal is to create a Java App consisting of two eclipse projects
(i am working with eclipse oxygen), then build it with gradle and 
finally execute the .jar file.
The first project, called MPF, is independent and provides some functionality.
This is the content of its build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The second project, called MP, provides some other functionality and the main
method. It depends on the package MPF. This is the content of its build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
   jcenter()
}

dependencies {    
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile project(':MPF')
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'mypackage.StartApp'
    }
}
```

The MPmain project is the root project and contains the settings.gradle file
that looks like this

```
rootProject.name = 'MPmain'

include   ':MPF', ':MP'
project(':MPF').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../MPF')
project(':MP').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../MP')
```

and the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':MPF')
    compile project(':MP')
}
```

The build is successful, but when I execute the jar file I get the following
message:

```
C:\examples\workspace_tests\MP\build\libs>java -jar MP.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage/StringData
    at mypackage.StartApp.main(StartApp.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.StringData
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

The StringData class is located in the MPF package and is not found
when running the built jar file.
It seems there is something missing in the gradle configuration files.
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: you need to create a **runnable** jar. there are more than plenty questions about this on SO.